# Using Shopify API inside Tapcart custom block?

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

I am exploring some updates to the product page on my Shopify [Tapcart](https://apps.shopify.com/shopify-mobile-apps) mobile app. I will have to make use of Custom blocks and the Shopify API to retrieve a list of products and their tags. Unfortunately, I have read the [Shopify ajax documentation](https://shopify.dev/api/ajax) which says:

> You can't use the Ajax API on a Shopify custom storefront.

As Tapcart does count as a custom storefront, is there an alternative method to retrieve a list of products on my Shopify site?

Comment: Why would you need to make a call to your store for product info? Tapcart exists solely to already give you all the product info you get want right? Why else would you pay for Tapcart? Makes no sense. But anyway, if you had to make a JS call to get product info, just get yourself a storefront API key token to the store, and use that.

Comment: Shopify ajax API only works because it executes within a store on Shopify servers... so yes, it needs no auth. That does not help you. Hence why I suggested Storefront API, which is actually for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do this, here's a boilerplate example:

(You can go here for other examples too - https://github.com/Tapcart-Templates)

```
const STOREFRONT_ACCESS_TOKEN = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
const GRAPHQL_URL = "https://tapcart-boutique.myshopify.com/api/2022-10/graphql.json";
const productIds = `["gid://shopify/Product/7444358463640"]`;
const productQuery = () => `
  query {
    nodes(ids: ${productIds}) { 
      ... on Product {
        id
        title
        handle
        tags
      }
    }
  }
`;

const GRAPHQL_BODY = () => {
  return {
    async: true,
    crossDomain: true,
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "X-Shopify-Storefront-Access-Token": STOREFRONT_ACCESS_TOKEN,
      "Content-Type": "application/graphql",
    },
    body: productQuery(),
  };
};

fetch(GRAPHQL_URL, GRAPHQL_BODY())
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((productResponse) => {
    console.log(productResponse);
  });
```

When you've retrieved all the needed product IDs from Shopify, you can use the `openProduct` app action to switch to different PDPs. Make sure to use the `isRelatedProduct` boolean (set it to `true`) to ensure the transition is smooth as butter.

https://docs.tapcart.com/docs/app-actions

Comment: Thanks for suck a detailed response, I was able to develop a solution using the expanded [Javascript Buy SDK](https://shopify.github.io/js-buy-sdk/?shpxid=ca93bcbc-D4CD-4304-AB82-C998DBD308BE#expanding-the-sdk) And yes the `isRelatedProduct` parameter is great and perfect for what was required.